# Map entire subdomain to Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy

Is there a way to map an entire subdomain to an Azure Function and pass in the folder structure without proxying it through a VM or App Service? For instance, https://example.com/path/to/name would pass into an Azure Function something like "path/to/name"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with the help of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies.

After creating a new Function App with an Azure Function using JavaScript with an HTTP Trigger, create a Functions Proxy with a route template of `{*path}` and a Backend URL of `https://localhost/api/<trigger name>?code=<trigger code>&path={path}`. On a GET, the path is available at `req.query.path`, and the original url is available at `req.originalUrl`.

Comment: This is close, but it doesn't give the original URL as submitted by the browser. The proxy masks the original URL as 'localhost'. and passing the path through only gives the path. Some people will need the whole domain.

Comment: I'm wrong, I didn't care about forwarding the path as I thought I could access the original url without it. Turns out, that's a necessary step and azure will change all the originalUrls when it's included, and will NOT do so if not included. Shrug. However I'm not seeing the path being passed through.